# Dynamic layout of WPF controls which depends on some condition

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I'm using WPF and I have a problem with layouting. I have got a docked panel (non WPF, I just hosted my control inside). And when a user wishes to dock this panel on the left or the right of the screen, I need to layout my controls in one way. But when the user wishes dock this panel on top or bottom, I need to layout my controls in another way.

My question is what is the best way to implement dynamic layout of WPF controls, which depends on some conditions?

I understand, that I can use the grid and dynamically change positions of my controls inside the grid. But I am not really happy with this solution. I'm looking for a solution with no code intervention, xaml only. And in case this is impossible, at least involving minimum intervention in the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) to get a docking system very much like visual studio's. 
This would give your users full control on the layout they desire, and it's not too hard to implement.

But if you really want a quick way to do this, I'd recommand Binding the `DockPanel.Dock` property to a ViewModel value that changes upon user input (along with an `IValueConverter` if necessary).

Comment: I agree with this. `AvalonDock` can give you what you seek. There are also Infragistics, Telerik controls.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm already using native Visual Studio docked panel, I'm developing a Visual Studio package :) The binding of DockPanel.Dock is a good and simple solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

For this purposes DataTemplate feature is.

The idea is to provide multiple DataTemplates and then using your custom inplementation of the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) rturn right DataTemplate based on criteria.

- For an example see [my post regarding DataTemplates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877645/wpf-list-of-different-types-of-user-controls/7877701#7877701)
- [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's a great solution for difficult differences of controls layout! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry stackoverflow.com doesn't support two answers at the same time, but your answer is good solution too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use StoryBoard and change the transformation of controls

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm think, that is solution difficultly to maintain and requires more time to implementation than the another solutions.